# Activate Apache/PHP on Mac OS X 10.8.3

Tags: php, macos, apache

I have a MacBook Pro with OS X 10.8.3 factory installed. I want to set up a working Apache/PHP environment on my local machine. Is this a matter of activating/changing settings in Terminal or do I need to install something?

There have been other guides out there but they don't explicitly answer how to begin if I have a factory installed OS and not an upgrade from an earlier version.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8):

If I'm not mistaken, all you have to do is edit the httpd.conf (/etc/apache2/httpd.conf) file to load the php module into apache (Look for 'LoadModule php5_module', it will probably be there, but with a # at the beginning of the line, simply remove it) and then start apache by entering this in terminal: `apachectl start` (you will maybe need to put 'sudo' before)

Of course this will only run apache and php. After that you can change your documentRoot and all the settings you want

Comment: thanks for info. This is accurate for how I did it although I needed some more hand-holding as far as terminal commands. OS X 10.8 is a little quirky when it comes to setting up user document roots. The link I posted explains that in more detail if someone wants to configure separate roots for different users.

Comment: yes that's true, I upgraded from 10.6.8 not so long ago, and I struggled a little with the document roots too

Answer (score 7):

I found a guide that'll walk someone through getting the factory installed Apache and PHP working on OS X 10.8. It goes over getting MySQL installed too:

http://coolestguyplanettech.com/downtown/install-and-configure-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-osx-108-mountain-lion